# Good style in GUI Development

Tags: user-interface, coding-style

Now I'm developing some standalone application with GUI. But I haven't enough experience. So, what is **good style** to create module, flexible UI:

- Build all components tree **in one place**.
  *or*
- Parent know only about its children. **Not deeper than one level** in hierarchy.

Thanks.

Comment: What language/platform are you developing on?

Comment: It doesn't matters, but _Java_.

Comment: It _does_ matter because different languages have different facilities for GUI development. What is right for one may not be right for another

Comment: OK. Can you tell how you develop? It would be very interesting for me. :)

Comment: I don't tend to develop GUI toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

you don't mention your language.

In Java look at the Swing library.  It has object oriented structures defined with well documented message passing from object to object whenever events such as clicks occur.

Comment: Language doesn't matters. I asked about good developing (architecture) style.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single way that is best. For small applications it is convenient to create all widgets in one place. As the project scales up in size the more it will benefit from a more modular approach. If the GUI is highly complex its better to break the UI into chunks, but even then its not necessarary to strictly follow the "parent only knows about its children" rule.

GUI componants are not much different than other software componants, so general good practices apply.

Comment: Ok. Thx. Sorry, I have no 15 reputation to increment yours.